# Workbench - CVE-2021-44228

Tags: security, workbench

This is relative to the CVE-2021-44228 log4J vulnerability.  Is anyone aware as to the impact on Workbench?      A POC for Salesforce support said it was impacted.   If so - would anyone know how it would be patched?

Answer (score 2):

If workbench is using that Java library in the backend, it would have to be patched there (on the server), nothing you could do from your side. But I doubt that Workbench is affected, it seems to be PHP / JS based.

[image: code used for workbench]

https://github.com/jdrishe/Salesforce-Workbench

Comment: Btw: the official repository is on https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench